# Need help with Delphi and ADOTable filtering

Tags: delphi

i m trying to build an invoice program that holds data in an Access db. i have some tedit s, buttons, one datasource, one adotable, one dbgrid and a popup menu. database format is accdb.

Problem: i want the program to filter records while user is typing. it might filter dbgrid or tedit, doesn t matter. i somehow found some code, for example:

```
Table1.FilterOptions:=[foCaseInsensitive];
Table1.Filter:='Filmadi='+QuotedStr(Edit1.Text+'*');
Table1.Filtered:=true;
```

the code above gives this error: Project Project1.exe raised exception class eoleexception with message: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal

other examples give various errors.

sincerely

onur

Comment: My first thought is that the oleexception is thrown because `Filmadi` somehow is not found in the fields collection (accessdb site of things) of the table accessed by `Table1`, but I assume you checked that it actually is a column name of that table... Another reason could be that you are using persistent fields: the fields added to your form/datamodule when you use the fields editor of the table at designtime, and didn't add `Filmadi` as a persisten field. But I can't remember whether the filter property even looks at that.

Comment: wait a minute, filmadi is a field name. i didn't know that. i thought it was a search pattern or something like that. thanks for the reply. by the way i had modified Table1 objects to ADOTable1.

Comment: i changed filmadi to title_txt but it gives another error: Project Project1.exe raised exception class EDatabaseError with message 'FilterOptions are not supported'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LIKE operator in your filter:

```
procedure DoIncrementalFilter(Dataset: TDataSet; const FieldName, SearchTerm: string);
begin
  Assert(Assigned(Dataset), 'No dataset is assigned');

  if SearchTerm = '' then
    Dataset.Filtered := False
  else
  begin
    Dataset.Filter := FieldName + ' LIKE ' + QuotedStr(SearchTerm + '*');
    Dataset.Filtered := True;
  end;
end;
```

Example:

```
  DoIncrementalFilter(ADOTable1, 'Filmadi', Edit1.Text);
```

Comment: what do you do if there is nothing in the database that mathces the filter and you get exception: `Cannot convert type (Null) into type (OleStr)`?